# Does it make sense to assign a variable to the result of a query returning several rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I just found the following code inside a stored procedure.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT @MyVar = MyField
    FROM   ...

    -- do something with @MyVar
END
```

The problem is that the query could return more than one row (not just a theoretical possibility, I know this might happen). What would happen if the query returned more than one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would happen?

The value in @MyVar would reflect the value of MyFIeld of last row returned by the query.

> Does it make sense?

No, but again depends on the rest part of the query.

Comment: Even with no `ORDER BY` clause? This is dangerous.